# microsoft office not properly working in wine

Tags: wine

I had installed Microsoft Office through Wine on my Ubuntu Desktop.

When I close my opened Microsoft word document, I was shown a dialog box that shows Microsoft Office Word has encountered a problem.

Also, When I try to open Microsoft Powerpoint, I get a message that Microsoft Powerpoint failed to start in safe mode.

Then I moved to skydrive with my hotmail account.

But Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Ankitjava - you didnt mention what version of office you want to run.  Office 2003 and Office 2007 works ok - use playonlinux to install these office suites to ensure the wine tweaks are applied correctly to enable the applications to work.

Comment: I am not really shocked by this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

Wine is a lot different from virtualizing. From [this link](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31) and the links to the specific programs, I'd say that 2007 shouldn't give you too many problems. What problems others have had is listed under the specific versions of each program.