# Microsoft Word, Excel and Powerpoint won't save or open files

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I'm a web developer, but new to linux.  I am currently running ubuntu 11.10 with a gnome shell and wine (I think 1.3).  I've installed microsoft office 2007, and worked through a small issue with powerpoint not running.  So one little issue left, I can't save files, and I can't open files.

I've checked all over the various forums, and haven't found a solution yet. I haven't yet tried to completely uninstall wine and start from scratch (I haven't done that because I've actually got photoshop working, whoo!)

Anyways, would truly appreciate some help.

Comment: with Microsoft Office? with not LibreOffice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the steps needed to install Microsoft Office on Linux (in my case Office Pro 2007, Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell)

1. Install Wine 1.3
2. Install Wine Tricks
3. Right click on office.exe file
4. Wine walks you through installation
5. Open Wine Tricks, select the default prefix
6. Click `Add Windows dll`
7. Add riched20 and riched30
8. Open Wine configure
9. Click `Add Application`, navigate to the individual .exe files (e.g. winword.exe, excel.exe)
10. For those applications, hit the drop down menu and select Windows XP, making Wine emulate Windows XP just for office programs.

Answer (score 4):

Wine has a [database of applications](http://appdb.winehq.org/) that may work properly in Wine with or without any required tweaks. Please check it first, whether [MS Office 2007](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992) needs any additional setup or not.

I have not tried MS Office in Ubuntu (or any other GNULinux distro) since alternative office suites like LibreOffice.org, OpenOffice.org are already there. And they work better, at least for me.

:)

References:
[microsoft office not properly working in wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64786/microsoft-office-not-properly-working-in-wine)
[How well does Microsoft Office Excel work in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1686/how-well-does-microsoft-office-excel-work-in-wine)

Comment: I checked the database, installed using the recommended process even tried using playonlinux.  I used my setup.exe file (it's legit, not a crack.) when the process called for it.  Everything seemed fine except powerpoint wasn't working.  I found the solution for that on a forum, which was great.  I just can't save or open files.  Thanks for the advice on Open Office!

Comment: okay I found a decent solution in the database (way down in the comments) like you suggested. If you use wine configure to make wine emulate windows xp instead of windows 7 then office works great. You can actually do this for a specific application by selecting add application and navigating to it's .exe file. (ie winword.exe excel.exe etc.)  Thanks, again!

Comment: @Costa i am glad you got the solution and you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

With Wine 1.4 and above you can open and save files.
If you have an older version, please upgrade:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

If it doesn't work, remove your `$HOME/.wine` folder and follow these instructions:
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992

If it still doesn't work, try upgrading to another edition.

Note that Microsoft Office 2010 works very well, and I can open and save my files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it by editing my winecfg.  Changing the Windows Version From Windows 7 to Windows XP did it for me.

Comment: Could you give some actual instruction on how to do this?

Comment: @RolandiXor I know I might be late for this, but here it goes: Type winecfg on the terminal, then click on "Add Application" and navigate to each of the Office .exe files. Add the ones you need. Then select Windows Version: Windows XP on the combobox you see below.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes you should post this as answer. This current answer could be deleted.